# GraphQL type descriptions with AppSync

Tags: aws-appsync

Is there a way to add GraphQL type descriptions to a GraphQL Schema used by AppSync?

ApolloServer and graphql-js support this with comments in the schema file (see [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/464) ). Is there something similar for AppSync so I can use GraphQL type introspection to see field descriptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a comment just over the type (note that it must be the line immediately before). It might look like this:

```
# A comment on a post.
type Comment {
    id: ID!
    content: String
}
```

Comment: Nice! It looks like AWS AppSync has added support for this.